# how does adding a ppa with a curl command work?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, software-sources, curl

[This link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) discusses different ways to install `nodejs` and `npm`. One of the methods was installing it via ppa.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

He used the above command to add the ppa. How does it work?

Comment: Probably because the setup script will add the PPA (or any apt repository) on your behalf. For example, installing the .deb file for Google Chrome adds an apt repository on your behalf.

Comment: Note that this is generally considered to be a bad idea, partially for security reasons, partially because there's a small chance if the download gets interrupted you could end up executing the wrong command (such as `rm -rf /usr` instead of `rm -rf /usr/bin/something/something`)

Comment: @immibis now that I understand, yes indeed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explanation of the line:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

1. curl flags and options:

   ```
   -s <==> Silent mode  
   -L <==> or --location, will follow redirects
   ```
2. sudo bash:

The minus sign behind sudo bash in fact means take the input comming from the pipe and treat it as a bash script. and that is exactly what this link contains, a bash script, you could as well use this line:

```
wget -O- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

Which will do exact the same.

Comment: This is incorrect; `-` here is analogous to `--` meaning end of options for `bash`, not STDIN. Actually in this case, one could just do `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash`

Answer (score 4):

Looking at https://deb.nodesource.com/setup, the following two lines of code add the apt repository for you when you run the script:

```
exec_cmd "echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10 ${DISTRO} main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
exec_cmd "echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10 ${DISTRO} main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
```

Answer (score 0):

You grant the shell script hosted at this address full access rights to your computer, which it then uses to add the source.

By omitting the `| sudo bash -` part, the commands that would be executed are instead shown, so you can review them, ideally before executing them.

Comment: If you add an apt respository and install a package from it then you are giving the maintainer scripts of said package full access rights to your computer. So reviewing the commands in the shell script before running them doesn't really help you against a malicious PPA operator.